# Android SeekBar extension

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have multiple Seek Bars on my activity (4) and for each there is a textView that suppose to show the progress of each SeekBar. I thought to extend the SeekBar Class and add to it's constructor a TextView Parameter so I can bind the two -> SeekBar and TextView . Here is my extended SeekBar class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekBarPlus extends SeekBar {
    private TextView numberOfDrills;

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context, TextView text) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        numberOfDrills = (TextView) text;   
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        numberOfDrills.setText(progress); 
    }

}
```

What is the Context option?

Now here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.simplemathgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.simplemathgame.SeekBarPlus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView numberOfAddDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfSubDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfMulDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mul_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfDivDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.div_drills_number);

                SeekBarPlus addSeekBar = SeekBarPlus((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.add_seek_bar), numberOfAddDrills);
    SeekBarPlus subSeekBar = SeekBarPlus((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sub_seek_bar), numberOfAddDrills);
    SeekBarPlus mulSeekBar1 = SeekBarPlus((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mul_seek_bar), numberOfAddDrills);
    SeekBarPlus divSeekBar1 = SeekBarPlus((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.div_seek_bar), numberOfAddDrills);

    }   
}
```

I don't know how to it wright! Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: won't work, because setText(int) expects a resource id

Answer (score 0):

try to use setter instead of constructor in your custom SeekBar:

```
public void setTextView(TextView text) {
    numberOfDrills = text;   
}
```

then in your activity, use

```
SeekBarPlus subSeekBar = (SeekBarPlus) findViewById(R.id.sub_seek_bar);
subSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfAddDrills);
```

you can also use normal Seekbar with OnSeekBarChangeListener:

```
SeekBar subSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sub_seek_bar);
subSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                numberOfDrills.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can also pass CharSequence: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: yes, but in this case, you call setText(int), which int is interpreted as a resource id.

Comment: rephrased : int != CharSequence

Comment: yeah you are right actually, it is needed to call String.valueOf(progress), I am sorry.